# How to retrieve wallets Transaction History for a specific spl-token

Tags: web3.js, node

I am trying to retrieve a list of transactions for a specific spl-token in a wallet.

```
    const tokenAccount = await getAssociatedTokenAddress(TOKEN_ADDRESS, keyPair.publicKey)
    const signatureList = await connection.getSignaturesForAddress(tokenAccount, { limit })
    const transactionList  = await connection.getParsedTransactions(signatureList.map(s => s.signature))
    const txList : ParsedTransactionWithMeta[] = transactionList.filter((tx): tx is ParsedTransactionWithMeta => tx !== null)

    const transferList = txList.filter(tx => tx.meta?.postTokenBalances?.length === 2)

    for (const tx of transferList) {
        for (const instruction of tx.transaction.message.instructions) {
            if(instruction.program !== "spl-token")
                continue
            if(!instruction.parsed)
                continue
            const info = instruction.parsed.info
            const sender = info.authority
            const amount = info.tokenAmount.uiAmount
            logger.info(`${sender} deposited ${amount} TOKEN`)
        }
    }
```

Feels cumbersome and probably error prone as well to manually look up the instructions. Is there an easier (and probably better) way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your algorithm seems generally how I'd write it. A better way, that would require a lot of pre-setup, could be listening to the specific account all the time, index each transaction as it comes in, then use in-memory access from there.

Your code gets the transactions for a given token account, then checks for the correct program, from the RPC, I think that is a pretty direct route for using RPC. I don't think there is an API to `getTransactionsByProgramId`.

Additionally, you can get pre/post token balances for a transaction, with the `getTransaction` API that you are using, if that's not already being used.